# Yii add another $content to template

Tags: php, javascript, yii

I have Yii template that structure is:

1. Include CSS files in
2. echo $content right after
3. Include Javascript files (like JQPlot) after $content

What I would like to do is add custom mix of Javascript/PHP code after including all Javascript files. I know this can be done just adding the code to the template.

But I have many pages with custom JS/PHP code and I would like to include only the specific code for that page to avoid long load times.

Can I create new element that works like $content, but it would include for example "js.php" from the same View folder as "index.php"? The "js.php" would be in every view folder I need custom code and contain the js/php mix of code for that specific page.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Check this out: http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/918-multiple-content-place-holder-variables-for-layout/

Comment: i would use a very customizable Portlet in your place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clips are your best bet, as @jfrej suggests by pointing you to a forum topic where clips are discussed.

Under conventional circumstances, every controller has associated a folder where all its views are placed, and it is the case that you want to include at the end of the **layout** (this is how they are refered, rather than *templates*) some PHP+Javascript content that is common to all the actions in the controller.

I would override `CController::afterRender()` method to capture the content for you clip; lets call your clip `controller_content`:

```
afterRender(string $view, string &$output)
    $this->beginClip('controller_content');
    // output here any content you want to capture into your clip
    // e.g. renderPartial, echo, etc.
    ...
    $this->endClip();
    parent::afterRender($view, $output);
}
```

Then, in your layout, you would render your clip after all the stuff that is always there, e.g.:

```
// register your CSSs
// output $content variable
// register Javascript
...
<?= $this->clips['controller_content'] ?>
```

Of course, there are various ways for you to generate your clip content. Here I overrode the `CController::afterRender()` method, but you could also use filters, behaviors or any other approach that best suits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can try : 
**Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCssFile(Yii::app()->baseUrl.'/css/example.css');**
**Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScriptFile(Yii::app()->baseUrl.'/css/example.js');**

You can call it from controller